# Why $pear->packageExists() returns always false on installed package?

Tags: php, windows, iis, pear, php-5.3

I installed Mail (http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) by

```
pear install Mail
```

everything seems to be ok, but checking for this package programmatically:

```
$pear = new PEAR_Registry();
$enabled = $pear->packageExists('Mail');
```

always fails for me (false).

Could someone give me any advice?

If I try to install Mail once again, I am getting:

```
pear/Mail is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.2.0
install failed
```

My include_path settings:

```
include_path = ".;C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.3\pear;"
```

Mail package was installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.3\pear\Mail dir

Reinstall Mail didn't help

Comment: checked your include path?

Comment: @ArunKillu question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong registry file.

Try to pass the PEAR installation directory as first parameter to the `PEAR_Registry` constructor. It's the directory in which the `.registry` directory exists, e.g. `/usr/share/php/`.