# Why PEAR_INSTALL_DIR has wrong PEAR path?

Tags: php, windows, iis, pear

This question is related to:

[Why $pear->packageExists() returns always false on installed package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397770/why-pear-packageexists-returns-always-false-on-installed-package)

PEAR_INSTALL_DIR has:

```
C:\php\pear
```

but this path doesn't exists in my system. I have PEAR installed to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.3\pear

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your system environment variables. See the second paragraph in the [PEAR manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php):

> Finally you have to add that installation path to your PATH environment. Either do this manually (Start > Control Panel > System > Environment) or run (double-click) the newly generated PEAR_ENV.reg that's now found in the PHP source directory.